# What does this mean 'Parameters to generic types must be types'?

Tags: python

I have a function signature:

```
keyword_extraction(content: str, channels=List[Channel.Game]){
   ...
}
```

But I got an error message:

```
Parameters to generic types must be types.
```

In my case, the List is of type Channel.Game, where Channel is an Enum in Python. What does it complain it?

Comment: If Channel is an Enum surely Channel.Game is a *value*? Can you give a [mre]?

Comment: If `Channel` is an enum, then `Game` is one of its values. You need it to be `List[Channel]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo, but I need to assign a default value. If I just use List[Channel], the default value won't be Channel.Game. How to deal with this?

Comment: But you mixed types and values... Did you mean `channels: List[Channel] = Channel.Game`?

Comment: Yes. That is true.